# SQL Server Import and Export Wizard: Data destination issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, visual-studio, import

I am trying to get familiar with SQL Server commands and procedures. So I have downloaded from my university's Dreamspark account the Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Edition.

My idea (call it personal project) was to try and import an excel table with dimensions 34162x465. And then within Visual Studio to try and manipulate it. For that reason I downloaded the SSDT for Visual Studio 2015 in order to use the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard.

I successfully researched and solved the first shortcoming, which was a Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 problem. 
But then, after I chose the excel file as a source, and when I reached the next step, to pick a destination, I chose SQL Server Native Client 11.0. The problem is that I cannot assign a SQL server because the drop down list is empty.

**I have already set up a local server (C:) and a database in Visual Studio's SQL environment, but I have no idea why the Wizard cannot detect its name.

Apologies if the question sounds ambiguous or I have missed any crucial details. Also, I have searched in various forums and online for similar issues but I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Sounds like a permissions problem. Have you tried to access with SSMS to the SQL Server using the same user as you VS connection?

Comment: @vercelli I haven't to be honest, but I will give it a go and see if it solves anything. Thank you very much!